# Is this an effective way to wait 10 seconds for an IP address?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops

I have a shell script that basically creates a vm that I use to do some processing on.  This VM is given a random IP address that I obtain using VMwares `vmrun` utility.  The machine can take anywhere from 10 - 20 seconds before it gets assigned an IP address that is not the default Windows `apipa` address.

Sometimes I get an arithmetic error, and other times I don't... whats wrong with this code? Why does it intermittently work?

```
IP=`vmrun -T ws readVariable MY_VM guestVar ip`
if [ ! -z `echo $IP | grep "169.254"` ]
then
  i=0
  while [ ! -z `echo $IP | grep "169.254"` ]
  do
    if [ $i -eq 10 ]
    then
      echo "$IP has been unresponsive for 10 seconds.  Now quitting."
      exit 1
    else
      sleep 1
      i=$((i++))  # This is where the error occurs
      IP=`vmrun -T ws readVariable MY_VM guestVar ip`
    fi
  done
fi
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Error Message:

```
arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "i++"
```

Comment: Should be moved to super user I think

Comment: @Petter I debated that too, but what about the code that fails?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @fedorqui I updated it with the error message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` looks like it's superfluous, you can simply use `((i++))` without the assignment to increment the variable.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `i=$((i++))` you could try:

```
 i=`expr $i + 1`
```